# Membership provider login does not use indexes because of a lower()

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I have a medium-large user base in `Memberships` and `Users` tables (more than 10.000 users). As the number of uses has grown, the login gradually process slowed down to unacceptable. Now it takes 2 seconds to authenticate one single user, which is a disaster for me. So I started to investigate what is going on.

It turned out that there is no index on the `Username` column in the `Users` table. So I created one. For my great surprise, it did not help. Then I sniffed the login process with SQL Profiler and found that the authentication request (`sp_executesql`, it is LinQ, not a stored procedure!) contains a `lower()` function on the `Username` column, making it impossible for SQL Server to use my index! Yummy!

My questions are:

1. why?
2. how to solve this, without rewriting the provider method (preferably)?

Comment: Did you share this scenario with MS using forums?

Comment: Not really. This forum is far better I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers of your two questions:

**Answer 1**: If functions are used in the WHERE clause this forces SQL Server to do a table scan or index scan to get the correct results instead of doing an index seek if there is an index that can be used.  The reason for this is is that the function value has to be evaluated for each row of data to determine it matches your criteria.For more explaination see [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/12/sql-server-avoid-using-function-in-where-clause-scan-to-seek/) and [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1236/avoid-sql-server-functions-in-the-where-clause-for-performance/).

**Anser 2**: While storing the username, store it either in lower case or upper case and instead of applying function on the column, apply it on the value:

e.g.

```
Users.Where(x=>x.UserName == username.ToLower());
```

or

```
User.Where(x=>x.UserName == username.ToUpper());
```

Comment: Thanks Nitin, but this is not an answer for me, this is an answer for Microsoft, who created this super inefficient query. They will not modify it for me for sure. And I don't intend to rewrite the whole Membership provider. Any other tips?